# Populating a table with CRUD functionalities

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution ASP.NET MVC where I manage materials with CRUD functionalities. Each material can have several packings attached. At this time, each time I add a packing to the material I save it directly to the repository. I don't like this way.

**What I would like**: every time I add a packing, I populate a table on my jQuery dialog and only when user click Save, everything (material + packings) is saved on the repository.

I wonder if something exist this way like a tutorial or plugin to point me to the right direction?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the table containing the materials. It currently only displays information about each material. All you have to do is include the corresponding hidden fields that will contain the information entered in the dialog so that when the form is submitted everything will be sent to the server and you could save it at once. Once the dialog is closed you will update the corresponding hidden fields with the values entered in this dialog.

Of course for the model binding to work you need to respect [the naming convention](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) of your hidden fields.

Comment: Your solution seems to respond to what I need: a hidden field to be posted back with other material info. Everything is saved at the same time. Now I don't know where to start? A kind of jquery plugin (like jTable) to manage my CRUD for packings (which fill the hidden field)? Does exist some sort of tutorial for this specific implementation? Thanks anyway you point me to the right direction.